# Replace a content type name with a different string, in a view

Tags: views, entities

I have a view that appears as the following table:

```
Title            Content type          Published 
------------------------------------------------
title1           content type 1          yes
title2           content type 2          no
title3           content type 3          yes
```

I want to be able to use a custom string instead of the content type name. My view should be like the following:

```
Title            Content type          Published 
------------------------------------------------
title1           my content1             yes
title2           contents for all        no
title3           other content           yes
```

I don't know is it's possible to do this with Views. I don't want to change the name of content types, I only want change them in the view.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the template file of you 'Content type' field for your particular view, and code in it.

```
switch($output) {
  case 'content type 1':
    print 'my content1';
    break;

  case 'content type 2':
    print 'contents for all';
    break;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I forgot to say you that this code was useful for me in the template "templateview.tpl.php" of the view, no in the template "contentype.tpl.php" of the content type.

Thanks again.